# How to ensure symbols will have the same size?

Tags: r, plot, rect

I'm trying to plot some squares on a map using the rect() function. All the squares should be the same size, but because of internal roundings (from decimal places in the coordinates to integer pixels on screen/file) some squares are bigger than others, some are vertical rectangles, other horizontal rectangles, etc. I tried using symbols() instead of rect(), but the problem remains.

Is there any way to ensure they'll have the same size and appearance?

Here's my code:

```
rx1 <- vector()
rx2 <- vector()
ry1 <- vector()
ry2 <- vector()
gap <- 0.22
for (i in 1:nx) { # for each column
    x1 <- xmin + (i-1)*side
    x2 <- xmin + i*side
    for (j in 1:ny) { # for each row
        y1 <- ymin + (j-1)*side # side=0.5 degrees, the size of the cell
        y2 <- ymin + j*side
        nInd <- spdf$nInd[(i-1)*ny+j] # calculate the number of individuals for that cell
        if (nInd >= 1 & nInd < 4) {
            rx1[length(rx1)+1] <- x1+gap
            ry1[length(ry1)+1] <- y1+gap
            rx2[length(rx2)+1] <- x2-gap
            ry2[length(ry2)+1] <- y2-gap
        }
    }
}
rect(rx1,ry1,rx2,ry2,col=NA,border="black")
```

Comment: Appreciate the amount of code provided, but I can't run it without `nx`, `ny`, `xmin`, `ymin`, `side` and `spdf`. Without really seeing your problem, for a solution I would suggest saving your plot as a PDF or as a raster image with high resolution.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to prepare some data so you can see what's happening.